# Not sure if addTestDevice is working for me

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I added a test device to my android project with adMob ads:

```
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("F35A072ADB96483A63DBxxxxxxxxxxxx") 
            .addTestDevice("44A2BE69E1A09846302Bxxxxxxxxxxxx") 
            .build();
    newAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

But in the logcat I still see entries asking me to add the same device.

Am I doing it wrong or that's the normal behavior?

Comment: In your app you see a test ad or a real ad?

Comment: I only see test ads if I use test Ad Unit ID (ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111)

Comment: If you see a real ad you may be missing a call to `addTestDevice`. You can remove the `addTestDevice`, clear the log `adb logcat -c` and run the app again to see your device id.